# A strange warning from proc phreg (Survival Analysis) in SAS

Tags: statistics, sas

I am been trying to fit a Cox regression on a small dataset but I have come across a strange problem. Although the model runs well, I am unable to get an ouput from it. Instead in the log one reads

```
WARNING: The OUTPUT data set has no observations due to the presence of time-dependent explanatory
         variables.
```

It's true that I have a time dependent variable on the RHS but this shouldn't be a problem, I think. Many analyses use this kind of variables. Could you please help me understand why that happens and how I can get past it? There is plenty of information to be got from this statement and it would be really helpful to me. Here is my dataset and the code I have been using so far.

```
data surv;
input time event fin;
cards;
2 0 1
3 1 1
4 1 1
1 1 0
5 1 0
6 0 1
7 0 0
8 1 1
9 0 0
10 1 0
;
proc phreg data=surv;
model time*event(0)=fin ft;
ft=fin*log(time);
output out=b;
run;
```

Wasn't sure whether I should post it here or in stats stack.exchange but in any case, I would really appreciate some help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

SAS is just telling you that you have a time dependent variable (it doesn't impede the code from running). You are violating the proportional hazards assumption for the Cox PH test, but the test is robust enough to handle it.  There is really no "correct" answer here.  You can perform some transformations and run the model after each transformation.  Whichever model returns the lowest AIC would be your best model.  Check out [this presentation.](https://stat.ethz.ch/education/semesters/ss2011/seminar/contents/presentation_3.pdf) Also, [this lecture](http://www.unc.edu/courses/2010spring/ecol/562/001/docs/lectures/lecture24.htm) has some good information as well. IF however the PH assumption is not important, you should switch to a parametric model.  I hope this is what (or somewhat) close to what you were looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your input. This is just a toy dataset, my real one is huuuuge. My problem is that I have to perform diagnostics with these time dependent variables in the model.